# How do I sbt test continually until a flakey test fails?

Tags: scala, sbt

If there is a test that fails only sometimes, can I ask sbt to run tests continually until failure?

Otherwise, I'm stuck hitting up-arrow while watching Arrow. (pun unintended but leavening)

https://stackoverflow.com/q/22366719/1296806

Comment: The only way i can think of, to tag the tests you want and run `~testOnly` on this tag

Comment: maybe you could define your own task/command in sbt that loops and invokes the testOnly task until it fails?

Comment: would need to be a command (not task), I believe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Old question, but having just had the same need myself, here is a solution: sbt will return non-zero exit code if you run it one off with the tests, so, one way to loop until it fails is to just look at the exit code in the shell:

```
while [ $? -eq 0 ]; do sbt test; done
```

Comment: Not one to be stingy with the green.

Comment: I did something similar with `for i in {1..100}; do sbt "<subproject-name>/testOnly *<class-name>; done` to have it repeat a set number of times. Would be nice to not load SBT every time since that takes the bulk of the time. This is prolly doable using Ammonite-REPL instead of SBT

Comment: My one liner: `i=0; while sbt siteService/test; do echo -e "Count: $i\n\n\n\n\n"; i=$((i+1)); sleep 0.2; done; echo $i`

Comment: is it possible to write the equivalent as a SBT task ?

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem, and I've ended up implementing this as a command.

```
lazy val root = Project("test", file(".")).
  settings(commands += Command.command("testUntilFailed") { state =>
    "test" :: "testUntilFailed" :: state
  })
```

The advantage is that it will skip the SBT loading. You can also add extra parameter or run `testOnly` to test a single test.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Much quicker to run.

Comment: @SaadMalik the green check means "that solved my problem". Upvotes mean good answer. Most upvotes means best answer overall.

Answer (score 1):

I have created sbt plugin for flaky test detection: [sbt-flaky](https://github.com/otrebski/sbt-flaky). You can run test for:

- specified duration `sbt clean "flaky duration=30"`,
- specified times `sbt clean "flaky times=30"`
- until first failure `sbt clean "flaky firstFail"`.

Advantage of this plugin is aggregation of failures, history trends and possibility of adding flaky test detection into pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it doesn't particularly apply to SBT or any other build management tool. There's no built-in SBT feature for this. You'd have to build one, but it'd be far from what SBT is meant to offer - build configuration management. It can take quite a while to hit the case which causes the build/test fail. It's very unpredictable.

When your test fails, it means that there are cases the test doesn't pass. The error should tell you what they are that you use to improve the test.

[ScalaCheck: Property-based testing for Scala](http://www.scalacheck.org/) might be of some help.

Comment: I did not downvote the controversial suggestion that sbt is not an interactive tool for doing things like `~compile` until I get the syntax right. Here, I was asking for `~test` until the flaky test fails.